# Syncing applications from iPhone to iTunes with multiple iTunes Store accounts

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization

I purchased applications from multiple iTunes store accounts, and when I sync with iTunes they are removed from the device. What do I do in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Likely this means you are not signed in and authorized with the secondary account you purchased the applications with, generally iTunes will report something on the lines of "You are not authorized to playback this content" blah blah I am going to erase all the stuff you are not authorized to play.

The fix is to go to the Store menu in iTunes and choose authorize computer, and enter in the secondary credentials, then you should be able to sync purchased apps from multiple account holders using the transfer purchases option, if nothing else.

Apple has some decent articles on the process:
[About iTunes Store authorization and deauthorization](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1420)
[iTunes Store: Transferring purchases from your iPhone, iPad, or iPod to a computer](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1848)

Comment: For excample i bought some apps with different accounts! Know before to connecting my devoce to pc for sync i must authorize all acunta on one ps and then connect my device and all will be ok? Nothing will delete?

Comment: Correct. The process is authorize computer, connect phone, when prompted, transfer purchases. If you are not prompted before you get the message that says "THIS WILL WIPE YOUR DEVICE", just cancel, right click the iPhone in iTunes under devices, and choose transfer purchases.